# SQL Server bulk insert int into bigint

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp

I'm trying to use the bcp utility to export a table to disk, remove the data, change the identity column on that table from int to bigint and then re-import that data.

When I "bcp in" the data I get massive numbers in the bigint column and not the original identity. I'm using to -E switch to keep identities and i've changed the bcp format file so that it's a fixedlength=4 column.

Can this be done?

UPDATE: I'm using the -N switch to use native database types. I've now tried using the -w switch and now I get a different errors regarding casts and text column data types.

Comment: Can you just copy the data to a temp table instead of exporting it? Or directly alter the column?

Comment: No, there is a billion rows in this table

Comment: Leaving the data inside of SQL Server is probably faster than exporting and importing it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added. The source server and the target server are different servers.

Comment: What about writing a simple SSIS package? You can use bulk insert, it will allow you to cast/convert accordingly, and will help you determine why you're erroring (better than the generic bcp error)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is yes it can be done. But not as it would appear using the native data types switch -N.

I used the -w switch and -t with double pipe delimiter "||". I needed this delimiter as some of text values had tabs and/or pipes.

I tried batch sizes of 1000, 2500, 25000, 100000. The best performance was from 25000.